# How to invoke a C# DLL function from powerbuilder 12.5 with a structure object as input parameter

Tags: c#, powerbuilder

I have developed a C# class in Visual Studio 2012 and registered the DLL. The class has two methods ( method1 and method2 )

I am trying to call from PB12.5 the method one as ( webservice is the name under which the class is registered )

```
lnv = CREATE OLEObject  
lnv.ConnectToNewObject("webservice");
ls_ret = lnv.GetPayerId(pcreatepayidinrec)
```

where pcreatepayidinrec is a structure object in PB.
Then I get "error calling external object function ..."

I believe that the issue is how to pass the input parameter when invoking the function, as when I try with simple ( ie string ) parameter, it works fine

Any assistance is kindly appreciated

Thanx
J

Comment: Did you mark your C# dll as Com Visible?

Comment: Yes and this is proved from the fact that when calling with simple argument ie a string parameter the method , it works fine

Comment: My memory is fuzzy, but I think you might need to include the namespace: lnv.ConnectToNewObject("namespace.webservice")

Comment: Yes, it's "namespace.classname" in the connecttonewobject

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the structure just fine. I have never used "ConnectToObject" when using .NET controls in a newer PB program and it seems like the more challenging way to go-- but I might be misunderstanding something. If you specify the DLL as a reference and put it in the "USING" section for your PB object you don't need to use it like an OLE server. Sorry if I lead you astray.

I have a very simple example of a WCF web service that I created in PowerBuilder and consumed in .NET using an array of structure that might help you. 
One of these is a beginner, and others I expanded on to make more complex variations hope they help.

[DisplacedGuy - Creating PowerBuilder 12.5 WCF Service consuming via ASP.NET MVC4 Application](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/creating-using-a-powerbuilder-12-5-wcf-service/) 
[DisplacedGuy - My First WCF Service using PowerBuilder 12.5 .NET](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/creating-a-wcf-service-using-powerbuilder-12-5/)

There is another one or two on the site but these seems to be more popular, hth.

Rich

Comment: On link not working sorry - my website was hacked in process of fixing - linux and/or wordpress admins who can help for reasonable fee contact me please.